# How are operators called which affect the first operand instead of 'return' something?

Tags: naming-conventions, operators, math

I'm talking about operators which not return a value but modify (overwrite) the first operand.

Example in pseudo-code:

```
      add  :=  return op1 + op2
increment  :=  op1 = op1 + op2
```

Given this mapping schema:

```
add -> increment
subtract -> decrement
```

What could possibly be the names for other operators?

```
multiply, divide, power, ... (what else?)
```

I was thinking about `add->selfAdd`, `multiply->selfMultiply`, but these names are somehow stupid.

*NOTE: What's all this for? It's for an experimental programming language. Because of certain circumstances there may be only words, no operator signs, so I can't use `++` for `increment` or `*=` for `selfMultiply`.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've usually heard *= and += referred to as "multiply-assign" and "add-assign".

Comment: This naming is more understandable than my proposal with addSelf. But sadly it's even longer to type.

Comment: Since no one seems to come up with a better idea, I'll mark this as correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are describing the differences between **[unary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation)** and **[binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operators)** operators/operations.

Comment: Not quite. Think of negation: it could be done as unary operator: `negate(someNumber)` (takes one operand) and as a zero-nary operator: `someNumber.negate()` (takes no operands).

Answer (score 0):

[This document about Java operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) names them *compound assignment* operators:

> You can also combine the arithmetic operators with the simple assignment operator to create compound assignments. For example, x+=1; and x=x+1; both increment the value of x by 1.